# giving the command in the directory where the file is located

Tags: command-line, cd-command

Stupid question time!

I've been toying around with Ubuntu for a couple hours and most of the programs I need are working just fine, but now I'm not sure how to install something.

> *[...]* giving the command `./tmc-netbeans_org_mooc_tmcbeans-linux.sh` in the directory where the file is located.

I have downloaded the file I needed to download, it's in my download folder... now what? How do I get into the directory from the file location?

Comment: You are supposed to use the command line if you weren't already (if not, press Ctrl + Alt + T) and use `cd` to move from one directory to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your downloads folder is usually `~/Downloads` (`~/` is your home directory). So, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and use the `cd` command to go there:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Once there, run:

```
./tmc-netbeans_org_mooc_tmcbeans-linux.sh
```

Tip1: just start typing `./tmcn` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, that will complete the file name for you.

Tip2: If it doesn't, you need to make the file executable first: `chmod a+x tmc-netbeans_org_mooc_tmcbeans-linux.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Open the parent folder of `./tmc-netbeans_org_mooc_tmcbeans-linux.sh`.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type `cd` then a space, and drag the folder to the terminal. It will add path of folder to terminal. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.